# Write an outlook message extension using SPFX

Tags: spfx, outlook

How to integrate an SPFX web part in Outlook email actions?

[image: Email actions]

I've been able to add entries to the menu:

[image: Custom app entry]

However, when I click on it, nothing happens.

No error message, no relevant trace in the browser console, and no failing network request.

The webpart, works properly when launched from the left bar (as a personal tab)

I didn't find much info regarding the scenario. All articles or videos I found are quite old and relate, I guess, to old versions of Outlook Web Access, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDubNXWZhb4), or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl4zu9YeeRA).

I've also saw [Building an Office Add-in using SPFx](https://www.spdoctor.com/articles/Building_an_Office_Add-in_using_SPFx.html) but, again, the technical details seems outdated.

If it matters, I have a webpart which works as a personnal tab, and as a compose extension. The manifest is similar to (removed non relevant parts):

```json
{
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "id": "fd5ac054-b292-4b1d-aee5-835417223142",
  
    "permissions": ["identity", "messageTeamMembers"],
  
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "abcdabcd-1234-1234-5648-1234567890abcd",
            "scopes": ["team", "groupChat", "personal"],
            "isNotificationOnly": true,
            "supportsCalling": false,
            "supportsVideo": false,
            "supportsFiles": false
        }
    ],
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "someid",
            "name": "Custom",
            "contentUrl": "https://{teamSiteDomain}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/_layouts/15/teamstaskhostedapp.aspx%3Fteams%26personal%26componentId=12345678-e90a-4afe-90ef-24441c6f3978%26forceLocale={locale}",
            "scopes": ["personal"]
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "12123434-aaaa-bbbb-9283-cceb4afccec6",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "somecommandid",
                    "type": "action",
                    "title": "Send hug",
                    "description": "",
                    "initialRun": false,
                    "fetchTask": false,
                    "context": ["message"],
                    "taskInfo": {
                        "title": "Send hug",
                        "height": "large",
                        "width": "1080",
                        "url": "https://{teamSiteDomain}/_layouts/15/TeamsLogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/_layouts/15/teamstaskhostedapp.aspx%3Fteams%26personal%26componentId=12345678-e90a-4afe-90ef-24441c6f3978%26forceLocale={locale}"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": ["{teamSiteDomain}", "some-az-endpoint.azurewebsites.net"],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
        "resource": "https://{teamSiteDomain}"
    },
     ....
}
```

The documentation isn't clear of what is possible, or what has been deprecated.

Thanks

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office/overview
And: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/develop-outlook-add-ins-with-sharepoint-framework/
And: https://spblog.net/post/2021/03/09/building-outlook-addin-with-spfx-save-mail-to-onedrive-with-azure-function-msal-net-and-ms-graph-net
You have to create a Microsoft Teams app with SPFx for Outlook and Office.

Comment: @MartinIszac: thanks for the links, but the content is outdated. The plusbeta flag is no more useful.